# Get NSData straight from AFNetworking 2.~

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am using AFHTTPSessionManager and I don't want the response data to be serialized. Is there any way to do this without using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to just add the following line of code

```
manager.responseSerializer = [[AFHTTPResponseSerializer alloc] init];
```